# sbt stops at first failed test (quick fail mode?)

Tags: sbt

Is it possible to make sbt stop at the first failed test?

For example, during a refactoring, I'd use that feature like this:

```
~quickFailTest
```

and I'd fix test after test.

Comment: This is probably specific to the test framework you're using.

Comment: It'd be better to have this in sbt.
For example, with testQuick, sbt can already start only the failing tests.

Comment: It can also be something generic at build tool level ... like running "update" on SBT or "compile" ... it's nice that SBT is pushing to run the command on all projects but what if you _generically_ whant SBT commands to just stop on the first failure ... (including tests) ... of course current SBT does not have that but it's something that can be desined at the build tool level at a future SBT version ... maybe !!